# Behaviour of event object when the onchange handler of a controlled react component is asynchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-functional-component

```
function Test(){
async function changer(ev:any){
let a=10;
console.log(ev.target.value) // reads correct updated state value
await chrome.storage.sync.get("sync") //---> fails to update the value if await is used 
// works correctly //chrome.storage.sync.get("sync").then((val)=>{
//  console.log(ev.target.value,a)
//})    
console.log(ev.target.value) // ev.target.value reads the older state value 
setVal(ev.target.value);
}
let [val,setVal]=useState("one");
return <>
<select value={val} onChange={changer}>
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</>
}
```

let root=createRoot(document.querySelector("body"));
root.render(<></>)`

`
Questions:

1. since react 17, the event object is not pooled. So, it must be the same even if the handler is asynchronous. But, statements after await read state value rather than the new click value fo the controlled select component. why is that ?
2. since the value prop is assigned to the state, event.target.value should point to the state rather than the clicked value of the select element. How is that react able to distinguish the value even thought the component it points to has the value={state} prop? is the event.target not live ?
3. will the event object be destroyed once the async handler returns an unfulfilled promise? what happens to the event object(which react claims to be synthetic) ?

I expected that the values between the console statements will point to the updated value but I get the state value rather than live clicked value in the second console statement.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MrwK.png)